# Downsampling multiple classes based on lowest value_count() of an specific column to deal with class imbalance in a generalized/line-efficient way

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on a dataset with some quite pronounced class imbalance. To deal with it, I'm trying to downsample the instances of all classes down to the same amount as the class with least instances.

```
wisdm["activity"].value_counts()
```

```
Walking       418393
Jogging       336445
Upstairs      122869
Downstairs    100425
Sitting        59939
Standing       48394
Name: activity, dtype: int64
```

In other words, using this as an example of what I'm dealing with, I'm trying to reduce all other classes to only 48394 instances.

After some quick research, I discovered sklearn.utils.resample's existence. Using it, I wrote the following code:

```
# Separating every class into different datasets
walking = wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == "Walking"]
jogging  = wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == "Jogging"]
upstairs = wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == "Upstairs"]
downstairs = wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == "Downstairs"]
sitting = wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == "Sitting"]
standing = wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == "Standing"]

# Downsample each dataset down to a n_samples equal to the number of samples in standing
walking = resample(walking, replace=True, n_samples=len(standing))
jogging = resample(jogging, replace=True, n_samples=len(standing))
upstairs = resample(upstairs, replace=True, n_samples=len(standing))
downstairs = resample(downstairs, replace=True, n_samples=len(standing))
sitting = resample(sitting, replace=True, n_samples=len(standing))

# Concat all the classes back together
wisdm = pd.concat([walking, jogging, upstairs, downstairs, sitting, standing])
```

This works, however, I feel there has to be a more generalized and efficient way to do this that doesn't involve manually separating the groups and then resampling them in such a "hard-coded" way. I, however, I'm quite new to this so I can't think of anything and would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a for loop:

```
sampled_dfs = []  # List that collects sampled dataframe for each category
smallest_n = np.min(wisdm["activity"].value_counts())  #  Find the lowest amount of samples for a category

for cat in wisdm["activity"].unique():  # Iterate through every unique category
    sampled_dfs.append(
        wisdm[wisdm["activity"] == cat].sample(  # Sample for that category
            n=smallest_n
        )
    )

df_new = pd.concat(sampled_dfs)  # Combine samples for every category
```

A method using numpy/pandas functions is probably way more efficient, but this is what I could quickly come up with that works for a generic amount of categories, without manually separating them.

Be sure to tweak the .sample() to your own needs, as I didn't check things like the difference in meaning of the replace parameter between sklearn and pandas.